# JavaScript calling function(int) with a regex match for numbers causes errors

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I'm using Node.js to make an app with electron. In my code, I have something like this:

```
var id = element.match(/(-?\d+)/g);
```

Where element is a string structured similarly to this:

```
The id of this string is 100, ...
```

I have an array containing objects called items:

```
var items = [];
```

The array is populated beforehand. Each item has a function called `getId()`, which returns its id, which is also a number:

```
exports.getId = function() {
    return id;
};
```

The program is supposed to pass the id to another function:

```
function getItemById(id) {
    for (var item in items) {
        if (items[item].getId() === id) {
            return items[item];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, when I try to use `getItemById(id)` with the id from the string match, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: items[item].getId is not a function
```

Which is strange, because when I try to do one of the following, I receive no errors and the program works as it should:

```
var item = getItemById(100);
var item = getItemById(parseInt("100"));
```

I need to get the id from the string as a number and pass it to the `getItemById(id)` function.

Comment: Add a `console.log(item)` and `console.log(items[item])` so that you can tell what's going on. And you really shouldn't use a `for ... in` loop to iterate through an array - use an index variable in a simple `for` loop, or use `.forEach()`.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Pointy Strange, the last element of items[item] is apparently a function, which has absolutely nothing in common with item. A normal for loop seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have found out the exact reason not to use `for ... in` loops on arrays :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The match functions returns an array of string that match with the regex. Assuming your input string contains only **ONE** number you should take the first element from the results.

```
var element = 'The id of this string is 100, ...';
var id = element.match(/(-?\d+)/g)[0];
```

**EDIT:** the error you're getting probably comes from the fact that `items[item]` is not of the type you expect, therefore no function called `getId` exists. Check how you fill the `items` array.

Comment: This is a valid point, but I'm not sure it explains the specific error that's reported. The `item` key has to be a real property name in the `items` array.

Comment: Just edited the post. Also, you should try what Pointy suggested in the comment to your question.